Memory Error python
Здраствуйте всем, писал код который должен считывать информацию и выводить совпадения из .txt, и нескольких .csv файлов
Сам код:
user = input('Введи айди:')
        os.chdir('bd')
        with open('data.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:

            result  = f.read()
            c = result.count(user)
            print(f'Количество совпадений {c}')
            input('Для вывода нажми Enter...')
            with open('data.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                for line in f:
                    if user in line:
                        print(line.strip())
        def search_in_csv(file_path, search_term):
            count = 0
            found_rows = []
            with open(file_path, newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
                csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
                for row in csvreader:
                    found = False
                    for value in row:
                        if search_term.lower() in value.lower():
                            found = True
                    if found:
                        count += 1
                        found_rows.append(row)

            print(f"Количество совпадений: {count}")
            input('Для вывода нажми Enter...')


            for row in found_rows:
                print(*row, sep='|')

        for name in 'part1', 'part2':
            format_bd = 'csv'
            delimiters = '.'
            result = name + delimiters + format_bd
            search_term = user
            search_in_csv(result, search_term)

Ошибка:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\zisho\Desktop\spiydex\main.py", line 49, in <module>
    result      = f.read()
  File "C:\python\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
MemoryError

По комментариям попытался сделать новый код для открытия txt файла, но теперь проблемы с табуляцией хотя все вроде нормально
новый код:
import os

user = input('Введи айди:')
os.chdir('bd')
with open('data.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        result  = f.line()
        c = result.count(user)
        print(f'Количество совпадений {c}')
        input('Для вывода нажми Enter...')
        if user in line:
            print(line.strip())

Ошибка:
line 11                                                                                                                                                                                       
    if user in line:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation


А какого размера файл и действительно ли он в UTF-8 кодировке? И 64-битный ли у вас Питон и винда тоже? Обычно 32-битному питону бывает памяти не хватает.

И лучше всё-таки не читайте файл сразу весь в память целиком. Если файл очень большой, то никакой памяти не хватит. Дальше вы построчно его читаете - вот там и считайте совпадения и суммируйте их.

кодировка utf-8. пайтон и винда 64 битные, а как сделать так чтобы код читал построчно?

Ну дальше после "нажми Enter" у вас тот же файл читается уже построчно

Не, все равно memory error

И всё же какого размера файл data.txt? И какого он на самом деле формата? Может там нет отдельных строк, весь файл - одна большая строка? Или может он вообще двоичный файл, а не текстовый?

если верить проводнику размер 1.787.135 кб, формат txt, а на счет двоичного файла незнаю

@zisho это 1,7 Гб примерно, при декодировании из utf-8 в объект строки будет еще больше. Насколько я помню, внутри строки как utf-32 хранятся, для оценки 1,7 удваиваем, получается больше 3 Гб. Скорее всего свободной оперативной памяти не хватает. Решение - не читать файл целиком в память с помощью .read(), а читать построчно, в каждой строке проверять наличие user

@insolor Построчно это как, можете написать или объяснить

for line in f: - это чтение файла построчно

с чтением построчно все равно memory error может я как то не так делаю

А f.read() убрали? Покажите отдельным блоком в вопросе новый код и новую ошибку.

@CrazyElf Я не знаю как новый код написать чтобы совпадения выводились

@CrazyElf Ну я вроде сделал, сейчас изменю стать и покажу

"TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation" - настройте свой редактор кода, чтобы он всегда пробелы для отступов использовал. Проблема не в коде, а в смешивании табов и пробелов.

Вы можете без проблем посчитать число совпадений в отдельных строках, а не сразу во всём файле, который, видимо, не помещается целиком в памяти:
c = 0
with open('data.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        c += line.count(user)
print(f'Количество совпадений {c}')
input('Для вывода нажми Enter...')



c = sum(line.count(user) for line in f)

@StanislavVolodarskiy Ну это не для начинающих )

Получатся что мы учим начинающих куда более сложной науке составления циклов, вместо составления выражений. Авторы SICP  не согласны.

@StanislavVolodarskiy На мой взгляд классические циклы понятнее и это правильно, что во всех языках учить начинают с них.

@CrazyElf Спасибо но как сделать так чтобы эти совпадения выводились я добавил 2 строки кода но не выводится: if userl in line:
print(line.strip())
